# Invalid Hook Call Warning Linking a react-app and a local npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

I want to debug an npm package that I am creating by linking my projects using `npm link`.

```
cd <my-npm-package>
npm link 
cd <my-react-app>
npm link my-npm-package
```

It works fine but if i don't use any thing that uses react hooks. 
But as soon as I use something like `useState()` in the my-npm-package project it trows some errors and my app does not run.

I did a lot of research but the only solution that worked for me was to install my package using

```
cd <my-npm-package>
npm npm pack
cd <my-react-app>
npm install ../my-npm-package/my-npm-package-1.0.0.tgz
```

I understand the Problem is because of multiple versions of react that are interfering each other. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Its a known Issue more information is described hire https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991

But I am new to this npm stuff and don't quite understand the solution.

package.json of the package

```
{
  "name": "my-npm-package",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Test npm package",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "socram",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Code used in index.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

export function test() {
    const [item, setItem] = useState("TEST")
    console.log(item);
    return setItem;
}
```

The react app used for testing is a newly created react project using `npx create-react-app my-app`

What is the best way to this issue? I don't want to run `npm pack` and then `npm install xxx...` it every time that I change something.

This is a better solution then to publish it to npm every time. But there has to be an better solution.

Result using `npm link` 
[image]

Result using `npm pack` 
[image]

Comment: `it trows some errors`. What are they?

Comment: Noting that helped much. It was about going to this page: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html I will provide a screen asap.

Comment: Yes tanks a lot for you support. I will provide then as soon as possible. I am on my why home now

Answer (score 20):

I had the exact same issue using `useEffect` and `useState` in a NPM package creation.

I followed step-by-step the instructions from React documentation on this issue found [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react)

This part of the documentation gave me solution:

> This problem can also come up when you use npm link or an equivalent.
>   In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application
>   folder and one in your library folder. Assuming myapp and mylib are
>   sibling folders, one possible fix is to run **npm link
>   ../myapp/node_modules/react** from mylib. This should make the library
>   use the application’s React copy.

After you link to the directory where your project is, then you can use `npm link` in the package directory and `npm link <your-app>` in your directory project.

For updating, use `npm run build` in your package directory and it should update right away.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, along with other recommendations to use resolve.alias, to no avail. I wonder what should be the exact configuration for both the project and the library in order for them to work properly.

Comment: Thanks, that could have been marked as a correct answer for me.

Comment: I found the paragraph before the last somewhat confusing, but this solved it. Basically you should have: Your Application `npm link`ed to your NPM package, and your NPM package `npm link`ed to your react. in my case react-dom too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to ingest a local npm react component library into a react app.

I fixed it by removing react from the `node_modules` in both the local npm package and react app.

I then made another directory at the same level as both these projects. In that directory I ran `npm init -y` then installed react.

I used `npm link` to point both the local npm package and the ingesting react app to use react from this react installed only directory.

Answer (score -1):

The rules of hooks lint rule uses naming conventions to tell whether code is a component, a hook, or something else. Functions that start with capital letters are assumed to be components. Functions that start with `use` are assumed to be hooks. Everything else is assumed to be neither.

Since you named your function `test`, it assumes its neither a component nor a hook, and therefore you're not allowed to use hooks in it. Change the name to either `Test` if it's a component, or `useTest` if it's a custom hook.

Comment: Yes I understand the naming Conventions. I didn’t choose the best naming for my example I am sorry. But this seams not to be the problem. Because my function works perfectly fine if I use npm pack instead of npm link.

Comment: Ok, well i can't do anything else without knowing the errors. I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: Yes I forgot to include them. It was really stupid of my part not to do so. The erro we’ll be added as soon as I get my hand on a computer